# How to use secret key in Play Scala application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, secret-key

I have `secret key` in `application.conf` of Play Scala project.

```
# See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret for more details.
application.secret="........"
```

How do I use it in my controller or service?

I tried with `application.secret`, it gives me error `value secret is not a member of controllers.Application`. WIth `play.crypto.secret` it gives
`object crypto is not a member of package play`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play provides `Configuration` object to access configuration keys from the `application.conf` keys.

Here is how you can get access to play `Configuration` object.

```
class HomeController @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller {
  def foo = Action {

    val appSecretString = configuration.underlying.getString("application.secret")

    //do something with app secret
    Ok(appSecretString) //app secret should not be exposed, just trying to show it on browser, but do not do this in production
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the `secretKey`